# c# winforms validate XML file on Form Load

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, file, validation

how i can validate the XML file on Form Load ?
( XML file is empty )

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // --------------- Read XML File / Data: Settings_General
    String xmlfile = "Settings_General.xml";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    doc.Load(xmlfile);

    XmlNode comboBox4Value = doc.SelectSingleNode("XMLFILE/Active");
    if (comboBox4Value != null)
    {
        comboBox4.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox4Value.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to validate against what? Do you have an XSD schema?

Comment: What do you mean by validate?

Answer (score 0):

If xml is in invalid format then `doc.Load(xmlfile);` will throw exception.